# Get dates for specific weekdays

Tags: php

I need to get the timestamp for the current week's Wednesday and Saturday at 22:59, and then convert the timestamp to a human-readable date.

I've tried the following:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

$wednesdayLimit = strtotime('wednesday this week');
$saturdayLimit = strtotime('saturday this week');

$wednesdayLimit->setTime(22,59,0);
$saturdayLimit->setTime(22,59,0);

echo date("Y-m-d H:i:d", $wednesdayLimit);
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:d", $saturdayLimit);
```

But I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setTime() on integer

Comment: `strtotime()` indeed returns an integer, and you're trying to use it like an object.

Comment: `$wednesdayLimit = strtotime('wednesday this week 22:59:00');` - but I'm not sure `strtotime()` will consistently handle the "<dayname> this week" thing, you should be sure to test it.

Comment: @Crontab I've been using strtotime() a lot, and it always worked fine. It's good that he's setting the timezone, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One liner:

```
print date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('wednesday this week 22:59:00'));¸
```

Yields:
`2016-01-27 22:59:00`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$wednesday = strtotime('wednesday this week');
$wednesdayStart = $wednesday - ($wednesday % 60*60*24);
$wednesdayEnd = $wednesdayStart + (60 * 60 * 24) - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use DateTime and do something like this.

```
$date = new \DateTime();
$date->setISODate((int)$date->format('o'), (int)$date->format('W'), 3);
$date->setTime(22, 59, 0);
echo $date->format('D d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/jq7HK).

Or, if you like one liners.

```
$date = (new \DateTime())->modify('wednesday this week')->setTime(22, 59, 0);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/EDLvC)